# Receive quantity of lines of query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Promt please.
I have an  query: `SELECT MAX(FPS.EndDateKey) WHERE FPS.EndDateKey <>-2`
I need to receive quantity of lines of this query in other query:

```
SELECT INVS.ParticipantKey, MIN(CASE WHEN FPS.EndDateKey <> -2 AND FPS.EndDateKey > FPS.DefinedEndDateKey
          AND FPS.EndDateKey > @PeriodEndDateKey AND FPS.DefinedEndDateKey < @PeriodEndDateKey
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0
         END) as InRunout,
         MAX(CASE WHEN DP.AccountKey = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as HasHSA,
         MAX(FPS.StartDateKey) as MostCurrentEnrollment,
         CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT MAX(FPS.EndDateKey) WHERE FPS.EndDateKey <>-2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  AS CurrentPlanYear
  FROM SupportFile.InvoicableSubscription as INVS
  INNER JOIN Evolution1.FactProductSubscription as FPS ON FPS.SubscriptionKey = INVS.SubscriptionKey AND FPS.StartDateKey = INVS.StartDateKey
  INNER JOIN Evolution1.DimProduct as DP ON DP.ProductKey = FPS.ProductKey
  GROUP BY INVS.ParticipantKey, FPS.EndDateKey
```

How I am able to do it? Prompt please. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "quantity of lines"?  Do you mean you need to know how many lines are in the actual query?  Where are you doing this?  In an application you're building?  Why not just count the lines yourself?

Comment: `"Prompt please"` - It's considered extremely rude to tell people that they're not helping you fast enough.  Especially before they've even had a chance to help at all, when you just *assume* that they aren't going to be fast enough for *your* needs.

Comment: @David -- There's an obvious loss in translation going on here.  I'm not sure the OP is using the phrase "prompt please" to mean "please help as fast as you can" or "you MUST help right now" or anything to that effect.

Comment: State what you've tried so far. Questions showing that you've done a degree of research (i.e. tried to solve them yourself first) are more likely to have people spend time answering them.

Comment: Maybe you just need the __COUNT__ of rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via a subquery:

Psuedo code:

```
Select Name, description,
  (select max(field) from table2) as maxtable2
from table 1
```